# Processing large files using Tcl

Tags: file, join, tcl, large-data

I have some information in two large files.
One of them(`file1.txt`, has ~ 4 million lines) contains all object names(which are unique) and types.
And the other(`file2.txt`, has ~ 2 million lines) some object names(they can be duplicated) and some values assigned to them.
So, I have something like below in `file1.txt`:

> objName1 objType1
>   objName2 objType2
>   objName3 objType3
>   ...

And in `file2.txt` I have:

> objName3 val3_1
>   objName3 val3_2
>   objName4 val4
>   ...

For the all objects in `file2.txt` I need to output object names, their types and values assigned to them in a single file like below:

> objType3 val3_1 "objName3"
>   objType3 val3_2 "objName3"
>   objType4 val4 "objName4"
>   ...

Previously object names in `file2.txt` supposed to be unique, so I've implemented some solution, where I'm reading all the data from both files, saving them to a Tcl arrays, and then iterating over larger array and checking whether object with the same name exists in a smaller array, and if so, writing my needed information to a separate file. But this runs too long (> 10 hours and hasn't completed yet).
How can I improve my solution, or is there another way to do this?

EDIT:
Actually I don't have `file1.txt`, I'm finding that data by some procedure and writing it into Tcl array. I'm running some procedure to get object types and save them to a Tcl array, then, I'm reading `file2.txt` and saving data to a Tcl array, then I'm iterating over items in the first array, and if object name match some object in second(object values) array, I'm writing info to output file and erasing that element from the second array. Here is a piece of code that I'm running:

```
set outFileName "output.txt"
if [catch {open $outFileName "w"} fid ] {
   puts "ERROR: Failed to open file '$outFileName', no write permission"
   exit 1
}


# get object types
set TIME_start [clock clicks -milliseconds]
array set objTypeMap [list]
# here is some proc that fills up objTypeMap
set TIME_taken [expr [clock clicks -milliseconds] - $TIME_start]
puts "Info: Object types are found. Elapsed time $TIME_taken"

# read file2.txt
set TIME_start [clock clicks -milliseconds]
set file2 [lindex $argv 5]
if [catch { set fp [open $file2 r] } errMsg] {
    puts "ERROR: Failed to open file '$file2' for reading"
    exit 1
}

set objValData [read $fp]
close $fp
# tcl list containing lines of file2.txt
set objValData [split $objValData "\n"]
# remove last empty line
set objValData [lreplace $objValData end end]
array set objValMap [list]
foreach item $objValData {
    set objName [string range $item 0 [expr {[string first " " $item] - 1}] ]
    set objValue [string range $item [expr {[string first " " $item] + 1}] end ]
    set objValMap($instName) $objValue
}
# clear objValData
unset objValData

set TIME_taken [expr [clock clicks -milliseconds] - $TIME_start]
puts "Info: Object value data is read and processed. Elapsed time $TIME_taken"

# write to file
set TIME_start [clock clicks -milliseconds]
foreach { objName objType } [array get objTypeMap] {
    if { [array size objValMap] eq 0 } {
        break
    }
    if { [info exists objValMap($objName)] } {
        set objValue $objValMap($objName)
        puts $fid "$objType $objValue \"$objName\""
        unset objValMap($objName)
    }
}

if { [array size objValMap] neq 0 } {
    foreach { objName objVal } [array get objValMap] {
        puts "WARNING: Can not find object $objName type, skipped..."
    }
}
close $fid

set TIME_taken [expr [clock clicks -milliseconds] - $TIME_start]
puts "Info: Output is cretaed. Elapsed time $TIME_taken"
```

Seems for the last step (writing to a file) there are ~8 * 10^12 iterations to do, and it's not realistic to complete in a reasonable time, because I've tried to do 8 * 10^12 iterations in a for loop and just print the iteration index, and ~850*10^6 iterations took ~30 minutes (so, the whole loop will finish in ~11hours).
So, there should be another solution.

EDIT:
Seems the reason was some unsuccessful hashing for `file2.txt` map, as I've tried to shuffle lines in `file2.txt` and got results in about 3 minutes.

Comment: Without seeing the code your running it's going to be hard to answer this question.

Comment: Ok, I'll update my question by adding piece of code.

Comment: @Jackson, please see update in my question.

Comment: 10 hours is a bit long. I've had processing of 32 million lines at 6 hours. For huge files though, I don't use `read` and instead use `while` and `gets` to get the lines one at a time (so no need to split and it doesn't consume huge memory in the few variables).

Comment: @Jerry, on my real test case, I'm getting following run-times: ~86sec for getting and writing object types to `objTypeMap` array (~ 4*10^6 records), and ~14sec for readaing `file2.txt` and writing data to `objValMap` array(~2 * 10^6 records), and I still don't have luck on writing combined data to a separate file, of course, I understand that I have ~8 * 10^12 iterations there, but should it take so long?

Comment: Seems this should take huge amount of time, because I've tried to do 8 * 10^12 iterations in a for loop and just print the iteration index, and ~850*10^6 iteration took ~30minutes.

Comment: You should think about importing that data into an sqlite database and using sql to create the result data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So… `file1.txt` is describing a mapping and `file2.txt` is the list of things to process and annotate? The right thing is to load the mapping into an array or dictionary where the key is the part that you will look things up by, and to then go through the other file line-by-line. That keeps the amount of data in memory down, but it's worth holding the whole mapping that way anyway.

```
# We're doing many iterations, so worth doing proper bytecode compilation 
apply {{filename1 filename2 filenameOut} {
    # Load the mapping; uses memory proportional to the file size
    set f [open $filename1]
    while {[gets $f line] >= 0} {
        regexp {^(\S+)\s+(.*)} $line -> name type
        set types($name) $type
    }
    close $f

    # Now do the streaming transform; uses a small fixed amount of memory
    set fin [open $filename2]
    set fout [open $filenameOut "w"]
    while {[gets $fin line] >= 0} {
        # Assume that the mapping is probably total; if a line fails we're print it as
        # it was before. You might have a different preferred strategy here.
        catch {
            regexp {^(\S+)\s+(.*)} $line -> name info
            set line [format "%s %s \"%s\"" $types($name) $info $name]
        }
        puts $fout $line
    }
    close $fin
    close $fout

    # All memory will be collected at this point
}} "file1.txt" "file2.txt" "fileProcessed.txt"
```

Now, if the mapping is very large, so much that it doesn't fit in memory, then you might be better doing it via building file indices and stuff like that, but frankly then you're actually better off getting familiar with SQLite or some other database.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works quite fast. Seems the reason is iterating over smaller data and searching name in larger one. I've changed my solution to do iteration in the same manner and got almost the same runtime.

Comment: @Donal_Fellows: Could you please help to understand is my guess correct?

Comment: I've shuffled lines in `file2.txt` and got almost the same runtime with may initial solution.

Answer (score 3):

Write the data to file1, and let an external tool do all the hard work (it's bound to be much more optimized for the task than home-spun Tcl code)

```
exec bash -c {join -o 0,1.2,2.2 <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)} > result.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm getting errors like below:
`join: file 1 is not in sorted order`
`join: file 2 is not in sorted order`

Comment: I've tried to sort them with `-k 1b,1` option, that solved the problem, but the output is not correct, I'm getting only the object names appearing 3times on each line.

Comment: I'm curious: how long did this take to complete?

Comment: This took about 1 minute. But seems something is not clear there, as my output file has only 2722 lines. And this in case when file2 has ~2million lines and file1 has about 4 million lines.
And with other solution suggested below by Peter Lewerin my output file has 7250 lines.

Comment: You had to use `-b` for sort. The extra whitespace us most likely throwing off the join results too. How many results do you expect?

Comment: Ok, I expect to get ~ 2 million lines as all object names of `file1.txt` should be contained in `file2.txt`.

Comment: And seems I don't have extra whitespaces around object names.

Comment: Please show a small sample of data that demonstrates the problem [mcve]

Comment: I can not share the real data used in my real program, but I'll try to reproduce the issue on a different test case.

Comment: I can not reproduce the issue on a smaller data :(

Comment: I feel there's a simple answer but we need some data to see. Are there duplicate obj names? What are the delimiters?

Comment: Yes, there are duplicate object names in `file2.txt`.

Comment: and are they all supposed to show up in the results? You did not specify your requirements well enough.

Comment: Yes, actually at the beginning I was thinking that there shouldn't be duplicate names in `file2.txt`. What I need is to find out object type defined in `file1.txt` for each object of `file2.txt`.

Comment: Please update your question with the new requirements, and add the desired output to your sample files.

Comment: I've updated my question, thanks for all your help! Seems Peter Lewerin's answer works with these requirements.

Answer (score 1):

A pure-Tcl variant of Glenn Jackman's code would be

```
package require fileutil
package require struct::list

set data1 [lsort -index 0 [split [string trim [fileutil::cat file1.txt]] \n]]
set data2 [lsort -index 0 [split [string trim [fileutil::cat file2.txt]] \n]]
fileutil::writeFile result.txt [struct::list dbJoin -full 0 $data1 0 $data2]
```

But in this case each row will have *four* columns, not three: the two columns from file1.txt and the two columns from file2.txt. If that is a problem, reducing the number of columns to three is trivial.

The file join in the example is also full, i.e. all rows from both files will occur in the result, padded by empty strings if the other file has no corresponding data. To solve the OP's problem, an inner join is probably better (only rows that correspond are retained).

`fileutil::cat` reads the contents of a file, `string trim` removes leading and trailing whitespace from the contents, to avoid empty lines in the beginning or end, `split ... \n` creates a list where every row becomes an item, `lsort -index 0` sorts that list based on the first word in every item.

The code is verified to work with Tcl 8.6 and `fileutil` 1.14.8. The `fileutil` package is a part of the `Tcllib` companion library for Tcl: the package can be individually upgraded to the current version by downloading the Tcl source and copying it to the relevant location in the Tcl installation's `lib` tree (`C:\Tcl\lib\teapot\package\tcl\teapot\tcl8\8.2` in my case).

Quick-and-dirty install: download `fileutil.tcl` from [here](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/artifact/5c945775454414cf) (use the Download button) and copy the file to where your other sources are. In your source code, call `source fileutil.tcl` and then `package require fileutil`. (There may still be compatibility problems with Tcl or with e.g. the `cmdline` package. Reading the source may suggest workarounds for such.) *Remember to check the license conditions for conflicts.*

Documentation: [fileutil](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html) package, [lsort](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsort.htm), [package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm), [struct::list](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/struct/struct_list.html) package

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm getting `invalid command name "fileutil::writeFile"` error when running this script

Comment: @Heghine: `fileutil::cat` is ok but `fileutil::writeFile` isn't? That's really peculiar.

Comment: Yes, it is, I'm getting error only on `fileutil::writeFile`
`invalid command name "fileutil::writeFile" like below
    while executing
"::_unknown_ fileutil::writeFile result1.txt {{name 1 val1 name1  type1..."
    ("uplevel" body line 1)
...`

Comment: Actually, I'm even able to print `data1`and `data2` lengths (and they are correct). And then I'm getting above error.

Comment: @Heghine: what's your Tcl version / `fileutil` version?

Comment: @Peter_Lewerin: my Tcl version is 8.4. How can I get `fileutil` version?

Comment: @Heghine: the result of `package require fileutil` is the version number.

Comment: @Peter_Lewerin: My `fileutil` version is 1.8.

Comment: @Heghine: I strongly recommend that you upgrade 1) Tcl, 2) [Tcllib](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/wiki?name=Downloads), or at least [fileutil](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/artifact/5c945775454414cf).

Comment: @Peter_Lewerin: I agree with you, I'm doing this for a company, so, I have no permissions to do such updates, so, I'll choose some other way to write my output. Thanks a lot!